# VSTS-hosted build agents refuse to run due to false capability error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are using VSTS to build a typical ASP.NET MVC web application. It had previously been working on hosted build agents, and they currently work on local agents.

We are trying to get them to use hosted Visual Studio 2017 build agents, so we don't rely on developers' laptops, and even bought additional build minutes. However, when I try to queue a build against the hosted Visual Studio 2017 agent queue, I get the following error:

> No registered agents found in the selected queue with the following
>   capabilities: azureps, npm, yarn, node.js, msbuild, visualstudio,
>   vstest, sqlpackage

These hosted agents should have all of those and when I look in the capabilities of the agent queue, it appears to have everything yet it still will not build. If I tell it to queue anyway, the build fails, saying:

> No registered agents found in the selected queue with the following
>   capabilities: azureps, npm, yarn, node.js, msbuild, visualstudio,
>   vstest, sqlpackage. Use a different queue. [More
>   information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=859777).

[image]

The build works great against our local agent queue running on our laptops. What could be blocking the hosted agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the [yarn task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn) in the build, but not the yarn installer. The hosted agents don't have yarn.

The build still demands yarn, but putting the yarn installer task before the yarn task seems to make it work.